# Force access to a page using a certain URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, detect, forward

I currently have a php application being hosted on a server and displaying under (for example): http://sub.site.com but I want users to access the page/site using: http://sub2.site.com.

This is because the current URL is being used as a connection to a game server and I'd like to serve this php application over a CloudFlare protected page (for SSL and Optimization).

Is there a way to get the page to detect what URL it's being accessed by and redirect to the other URL if it's not the desired URL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can check the referral url with the `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` variable anywhere in your code.

---

Example (psudo-code):

```
if($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] == "the url you want to detect" ) {
  header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
}
```